# Prevent excessive CPU usage of Golang background process

Tags: go, process, cpu-usage, htop

I am writing a Go program that watches files and run a system command if one of the files has changed. So far, it works well. I have questions regarding my main "infinite" loop because I don't want it to take all system CPU resources:

```
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
for {
    updatedFiles, _ := GetWatchMap(config)
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(filesToWatch, updatedFiles) {
        start := time.Now()
        _, _ = colorstring.Println(fmt.Sprintf(" [yellow] ⬇ Update detected[white] at [green]%s[white] > updating...", start.Format("15:04:05")))
        _, _ = Update(config)
        end := time.Now()
        elapsed := end.Sub(start)
        _, _ = colorstring.Println(fmt.Sprintf("  [green]✅  Done![white] in [yellow]%.2f[white] second(s).", elapsed.Seconds()))
        filesToWatch = updatedFiles
    } else {
        time.Sleep(config.SleepTime)
    }
}
```

So, what I have done is setting GOMAXPROCS, so it only uses "1 CPU/Core", and I have added a configurable sleep time in the else branch.

Without the sleep time, htop shows that the process takes 100% of CPU time (I guess it is 100% of one core?) whatever If I call `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)` or not.

If I use a sleep time of 30ms on my machine (MacMini i7, 12 Core) htop reports 20% CPU utilisation from the process, which seems OK, but I guess this will vary depending on the computer running the program.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: This is comment, because this isn't your question, but https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify provides an efficient file-watcher that uses your operating system to provide notifications when a file (or one of a set of files, or a directory) changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GOMAXPROCS does not what you think it does. From package runtime docu:

> The GOMAXPROCS variable limits the number of operating system threads that can execute user-level Go code simultaneously. There is no limit to the number of threads that can be blocked in system calls on behalf of Go code; those do not count against the GOMAXPROCS limit.

It limits OS threads. If your code doesn't use goroutines which *could* be scheduled to OS threads limiting the number of threads does literally *nothing*.
Just remove the GOMAXPROCS stuff, it does nothing. (If you set GOMAXPROCS to 12 you will have at most 12 OS threads actually executing goroutine code; If you have just one goroutine limiting  the number of OS threads it can run on is a noop.)

All you can do is not busy-looping as you did with time.Sleep(). Depending on *your* requirements you could call the actual code regularly, e.g. via a time.Ticker. There is no single "best practice" (excepet not fiddling with GOMAXPROCS).